# How to Override target="_blank" in the kml popup

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm loading a kml in a map from google using a code like this:

```js
var myOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=209879288832578501414.0004c52d678cf88f70685');
kmlLayer.setMap(map);
```

The problem is the link into the popup, [kml adds](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#description) `target="_blank"` and I don't want it.

How I can remove it using javascript? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185271/842697) but it doesn't work in the API 3. I prefer not to use jQuery.

Comment: The target="_blank" is actually in the kml:    <description><![CDATA[Hello <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">this is a link</a>]]></description>.  Why do you say the solution for v2 won't work in v3?  There may not be an [infowindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) "open" event, but it seems like the "domready" event might work.

Comment: Yes, the ``target="_blank"`` is in the kml. Google writes always it in the kmls. How can I obtain the ``domready`` event?

Comment: [addListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapsEventListener) on the infowindow for that event (same concept as the v2 example, just using v3 events and objects). You might need to add the suppressInfoWindows option to the KmlLayer and then add a click listener and create the infowindows yourself (so you can add that listener).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [@geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210329/geocodezip)'s comments I got a solution. It isn't perfect, the `InfoWindow` begins at the foot of the marker rather of the head but is something.

```js
var infoWindow;
var map;

function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);

    var opts = {suppressInfoWindows: true};
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=209879288832578501414.0004c52d678cf88f70685', opts);
    kmlLayer.setMap(map);

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlMouseEvent) {
        var name = kmlMouseEvent.featureData.name;
        var descr = kmlMouseEvent.featureData.description.replace(/ target="_blank"/ig, '');
        var dom = '<div style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small">' +
            '<div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; margin-bottom: 0em">' +
            name +
            '</div>' +
            '<div>' +
            descr +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>';
        infoWindow.setContent(dom);
        infoWindow.setPosition(kmlMouseEvent.latLng);
        infoWindow.open(map);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By jQuery,

Do this after your map is loaded,

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').prop('target','_self');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but doesn't work. When the map is loaded the popups are not loaded. And I don't know how to obtain the event "popup opened".